# Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF web app and I"m trying to access a SQL 2000 database, but I'm getting the following error:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Any idea how I can fix this? I probably need an example as I'm new to this and this is my first WPF application.

Comment: What is a "WPF Web App"?  Do you mean XBAP?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try switching to full trust application.

[image]

Comment: It's a little more complicated if it's XBAP - see here http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/maxim/archive/2008/03/05/wpf-xbap-as-full-trust-application.aspx for more information.

Comment: Thank you that did it, brilliant and super quick!

Comment: Even if "full trust" is already selected, try to uncheck then check again "Enable ClickOnce Security Settings". It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your application lacks the necessary permissions to connect to the SQL database.  Try running it as an administrator (it may be easiest to simply launch Visual Studio as admin).

Answer (score 0):

Full trust + Enable ClickOnce Security Settings make code conect server again.

Curious this PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089', I thoug was the signing my applications, seems MS uses for a generic security setting