# Cannot connect to SQL Server 2008 Express from C# (VS2010)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212973/request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqlclientpermission-s)

My first attempt at writing a C# front-end for a database is going pretty poorly right now, so hopefully I can get some help.

I downloaded and installed a fresh copy of VS2010 (90 day trial) and SQL Server Express 2008 R2. I've created a new database called MyDB. If I open SQL Server Configuration Manager, I can see SQL Server (MyDB) and SQL Server Browser, both are running. I can connect to the server with SQL Server Management Studio, make new databases, tables, etc.

In VS I imported System.Data.SqlClient. I create a new connection like such

```
SqlConnection myDatabase = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=localhost\MyDB;Initial Catalog=main;Trusted_Connection=True");
```

However, when I try to open it

```
myDatabase.Open();
```

I get a Security Exception:

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

I've read a pile of related SO posts and online, but have gotten no further. I've enabled every protocol in Config Mgr, I've restarted the services countless times, I've added user permissions everywhere I could find and tried using "user id" and "password" instead of trusted connection in my connection string. Nada.

Comment: What kind of C# project did you create? Try a console program as a first step to determine what is going on.

Comment: "Please refer to the following articles to configure the assembly to make sure it is set to fulltrust." http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqlreportingservices/thread/90bc9167-af50-42ac-be5a-4f10dc7cc652 (note the links are specific to SSRS). You probably need to the same for your assembly.

Comment: Haven't you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212973/request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqlclientpermission-s

Comment: @AlexR. has a better link than my comment

Comment: @Alex R. I had previously set my project to Full Trust and created a certificate. Just in case, I deleted my project and created a new one, enabled Full Trust and generated a new signed test certificate, and it's working fine now! Thanks a lot. If you post an answer, I'll be happy to accept, and I'll rep up that other link.

Answer (score 0):

I develop applications with VS2010 and SQL Server 2008 R8 myself. I really wish I knew what kind of application you were developing because I dont know how you want to connect to your database. On a second note, SQL Server 2008 R8 works best with 3.5.net, since your using 4.0, make sure you have the right correct sql server installed. You need SP1 to work with 4.0 if Im not mistaken.

Anyway, here is how I have mine set up.

```
<appSettings>
<add key="DataServerLEGOCUSTOM" value="GP2010LEGOCUSTOM"/>
<add key="DataServerLEGO" value="GP2010LEGO"/>
</appSettings>

<connectionStrings>
<add name="GP2010LEGOCUSTOM" connectionString="Data Source=GP2010;Initial Catalog=LEGOCUSTOM;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XX;Password=XXY" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="GP2010LEGO" connectionString="Data Source=GP2010;Initial Catalog=LEGO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XX;Password=XXY" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then again, the error could be in your code. You have to properly call your database and create an sql connection. So something like this

```
public class Database
{
    private string serverLEGOCUSTOM, serverLEGO;
    private string ConnectionStringLEGOCUSTOM, ConnectionStringLEGO;
    private SqlConnection connectionLEGOCUSTOM, connectionLEGO;

    public Database()
    { 
        serverLEGOCUSTOM = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServerLEGOCUSTOM"];
        ConnectionStringLEGOCUSTOM = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[serverLEGOCUSTOM.ToString();
        connectionLEGOCUSTOM = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringLEGOCUSTOM);
        serverLEGO = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataServerPCI"]
        ConnectionStringLEGO = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["serverLEGO"].ToString();
        connectionLEGO = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStringLEGO);
    }
```

This is just basically another way of connecting your sql database. Even though Persist Security Info=True may actually solve your problem. Hope this helps in some way.