# WPF Browser Application cannot connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2008

I am creating a WPF-Browser application. When I try to connect to a SQLSERVER 2008 database with the following connection string :

```
string sqlConnectString = string.Empty;
       sqlConnectString = "Server=SNPDBSRV01;";
       sqlConnectString += "Database=SQL2008;";
       sqlConnectString += "Initial Catalog=PSYSDBE_997;";
       sqlConnectString += "Trusted_Connection=True;";
       sqlConnectString += "Integrated Security=True;";
       sqlConnectString += "Pooling=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=120 ";
```

I get the following error upon trying to open the connection:

> System.Exception was unhandled by user code   Message=userLoginPage:
>       Sqlserver Open Error! Request for the permission of type
>       'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data,
>       Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>       failed.

Any ideas what's gone wrong? The connection string works fine for my Windows Form application.

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212973/request-for-the-permission-of-type-system-data-sqlclient-sqlclientpermission-s

Comment: OK. Problem resolved by Right-Clicking on the App.'s Property Tab, clicking on Security, and clicking the 'Fully Trusted' tab!